# Ordering PCA results in a higher principal component than 5

Tags: r, pca

I'm simply trying to order my variables in principal component 6.

I've tried fviz_contrib but this only goes to 5 dimensions for some strange reason.

My biplot is able to do this fine but I want quantitative data. I'd like to order the vectors that result from this code;

```
biplot(pca_result, scale = 0, choices = 5:6)
```

I have done this before with 'princomp' but if I use that I get an error that "can only be used with more units than variables," and if I transverse that I am getting pca of the units, not variables.

Answer (score 0):

Given a dataset - you will only be able to obtain `n` principal components, where `n` is `min(#features, #samples)-1`.

So in your case what is likely going on is that you either have less than 5 features in your data, or less than 5 samples.

Restated simply - the number of principal components cannot exceed the number of features you have, nor the number of samples you have in the data.